# Select com Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, query, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o seguinte select no meu controller:

```
$turmaAlunos = DB::select('
    SELECT alunos.ST_ALUNO_ALU, alunos.ID_ALUNO_ALU
    FROM alunos WHERE alunos.ID_ALUNO_ALU NOT IN (
        SELECT turma_alunos.ID_ALUNO_ALU
        FROM turma_alunos
        INNER JOIN turmas ON turma_alunos.ID_TURMA_TUR = turmas.ID_TURMA_TUR
        WHERE turma_alunos.ID_TURMA_TUR = ?
    )
', [$id]);
```

Ele me retorna o que preciso, porém como stdClass e isso está me causando o seguinte erro na view quando tento percorrer com o foreach:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$NM_MATRICULA_ALU
```

Minha view está assim:

```
@foreach($turmaAlunos as $turmaAluno)
    <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="alunos[]" value="{{ $turmaAluno->ID_ALUNO_ALU }}"></td>
         <td>{{ $turmaAluno->NM_MATRICULA_ALU }}</td>
         <td>{{ $turmaAluno->ST_ALUNO_ALU }}</td>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Aproveitando, existe uma maneira melhor de fazer esse select sem precisar de uma subquery? E como eu faço do jeito que está sem ser com DB::select bruto?

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa colocar a coluna `NM_MATRICULA_ALU` na sua consulta ao banco porque ela não está sendo retornada.

Muda a primeira linha do SQL para isso:

`SELECT alunos.ST_ALUNO_ALU, alunos.ID_ALUNO_ALU, alunos.NM_MATRICULA_ALU`

Comment: Erro primário esse meu :/
Muito obrigado!